# issue with dplyr package in R count function not recognizing groups within data frame

Tags: r, count, dplyr

I am re-running old code that used to run great using the dplyr package. It is now getting stuck at the point where I count the number of times a particular date appears in each group in a data frame called mutated_df, which is of the form:

```
> mutated_df
Source: local data frame [196,077 x 3]
Groups: Date [138]

Date Value     group
   (date) (int)    (fctr)
1  2016-01-28    84 upper-mid
2  2016-01-28   125       max
3  2016-01-28    78       mid
4  2016-01-28    NA        NA
5  2016-01-28    86 upper-mid
6  2016-01-28    NA        NA
7  2016-01-28   113     upper
8  2016-01-28    NA        NA
9  2016-01-28    95 upper-mid
10 2016-01-29   101     upper
..        ...   ...       ...
```

To get the counts I do:

```
c <- count(mutated_df, Date, group)
```

but get the error:

```
Error in count(mutated_df, Date, group) : object 'group' not found
```

The structure of mutated_df in more detail is:

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(16895, 16895, 16895, 16895, 
16895, 16895, 16895, 16895, 16895, 16895), class = "Date"), Value =     
c(89.5999985, 93.1999969, 86, 91.4000015, 91.4000015, 91.4000015, 84.1999969, 
84.1999969, 89.5999985, 93.1999969), group = structure(c(4L, 
5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("lower", "lower-mid", 
"mid", "upper-mid", "upper", "max"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Date", 
"Value", "group"), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -10L), vars = list(Date), drop = TRUE, indices = list(
    0:9), group_sizes = 10L, biggest_group_size = 10L, labels = structure(list(
    Date = structure(16895, class = "Date")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), vars = list(Date), drop = TRUE, .Names = "Date"))
```

Any idea about why this error is just now appearing in code that once worked fine? Thank you!

Comment: I can't reproduce the error message using the data you provided. Can you include the output from `dput(head(mutated_df, 10))` in your question?

Comment: Additionally, output of `traceback()` and `getAnywhere(count)` could help in debugging,Does this work `c <- dplyr::count(mutated_df, Date, group)`...

Comment: `c <- dplyr::count(mutated_df, Date, group)` gives the error `Error in group_by_(x, .dots = vars) : object 'mutated_df' not found`

Comment: That is very strange, possibly `count` function from `dplyr` library has been masked by another `count` function. To confirm could you include the output of `dplyr::count(mtcars,cyl,gear)` and `getAnywhere(count)`

Comment: That seems to work fine: `> dplyr::count(mtcars,cyl,gear)
Source: local data frame [8 x 3]
Groups: cyl [?]

    cyl  gear     n
  (dbl) (dbl) (int)
1     4     3     1
2     4     4     8
3     4     5     2
4     6     3     2
5     6     4     4
6     6     5     1
7     8     3    12
8     8     5     2` and `> getAnywhere(count)
2 differing objects matching ‘count’ were found
in the following places
  package:plyr
  package:dplyr
  namespace:plyr
  namespace:dplyr
Use [] to view one of them`

Comment: Did you load `plyr` *after* loading `dplyr`? `plyr` has its own `count` function that would mask the `dplyr` count function and could cause the error you're getting.

Comment: Yes, that was the bug. (just a note if anyone else runs into this issue, ggplot2 also imports the plyr namespace so it seemed like I had to unload both plyr and ggplot2 prior to loading dplyr). Thanks very much.

Comment: If you're going to use both `plyr` and `dplyr`, always load `plyr` first. If you load `plyr` after loading `dplyr`, you'll get the following warning: `You have loaded plyr after dplyr - this is likely to cause problems.
If you need functions from both plyr and dplyr, please load plyr first, then dplyr:`.